# Uploading multiple files to stripe.files.create (Node-stripe)

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am trying to upload files to stripe which are submitted by the user in my frontend to verify their identity before they can sell on my platform.

Currently, the files are sent via an API request to the backend where I can upload a single file, and afterwards, I attach it to that user's account.

```
let file = {
    data: fs.readFileSync(files.IDFront.path),
    name: files.IDFront.name,
    type: files.IDFront.type
}
stripe.files.create({
  purpose: 'identity_document',
  file
}, function(err, file) {
  if(err) res.send({sucess:false, error: err})
  else {
    //attach to user's account
}
```

This works just fine, but some identity documents require pictures of the front and back, so my question is can I upload two files at once using stripe.files.create? I can't seem to find anything in Stripe's API docs which mentions this, and I don't want to use stripe.files.create twice in one function because I feel that isn't a very efficient way to write the function.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Each `File` object needs to be created in its own call. You could write your own wrapper that accepts an array and loops over it to create multiple `File` objects via individual Stripe API calls under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that your documents still need to be sent to Stripe in their own calls in order to get their respective tokens.

The function below takes an object of document names and the returned stripe tokens

```
{ 
 document: <stripeToken1>, 
 additional_document: <stripeToken2> 
}
```

You can then iterate through these and append to the update object in one go

```
// create the document object template
const documentObject = {
    individual: {
        verification: {},
    },
}

Object.entries(imageTokens).map(([_, token]) => {
    const [keyToken] = Object.entries(token)
    // separate key and token from object
    const [documentKey, stripeTokenId] = keyToken
    // convert our naming convention to stripes expected naming
    const checkedKey = documentKey === 'document_front' ? 'document' : 
documentKey
    // append to document object
    documentObject.individual.verification[checkedKey] = {
        front: stripeTokenId,
    }
    
return await stripe.accounts.update(stripeAccountId, documentObject)
```

Comment: You should move your comment into the answer.

Comment: Do you have a github?